# Django - user_passes_test auth decorator - 'bool' object is not callable

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

Hi I'm trying to use the user_passes_test decorator [mentioned here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test).  But I keep getting this error:

```
'bool' object is not callable
```

My usage:

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_active() and u.is_staff())
def fulfillment(request):
    ...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

is_staff is a [field](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_staff) of User not a method. Get rid of ()

Answer (score 1):

another situation if you write a code like this :

```
newFile = open('pickled','w')
pickle.dump(newText, newFile)
newFile.closed()
```

as you see, `newFile.closed()` will trigger the same error, `'bool' object is not callable`

it's caused : `newFile.closed()` is a boolean value... and it's assigned to a variable or in equation or something else...